# How to read custom data from framebuffer

Tags: graphics, game-engine, vulkan

for the past few days I've been trying to implement mouse picking in my vulkan game engine and part of that is reading data from framebuffers. Now I can successfully read RGBA data. But what I need is to read specific attachment containing id of the entity.

Here is what my fragment shader looks like:

```
#version 450 core

struct VertexInput
{
    vec4 Color;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    float TilingFactor;
};

// Inputs
layout(location = 0) in VertexInput Input;
layout(location = 3) in flat uint in_TexIndex;
layout(location = 4) in flat int in_EntityID;

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D u_Samplers[10];

// Outputs
layout(location = 0) out vec4 o_Color;
layout(location = 1) out int o_EntityID; //  <-- This is what I need

void main()
{
    o_EntityID = in_EntityID;
    o_Color = Input.Color * texture(u_Samplers[in_TexIndex], Input.TexCoord * Input.TilingFactor);
}
```

And get this warning

```
Validation layer: Validation Warning: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-Shader-OutputNotConsumed ] Object 0: handle = 0x5dbcf90000000065, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE; | MessageID = 0x609a13b | fragment shader writes to output location 1 with no matching attachment
```

which is understandable.

I know I need to add attachment into my framebuffer object but I am not sure which one or how should I approach this problem. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. You clearly are able to add one attachment to the renderpass/framebuffer. So just do that again.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I can just use another COLOR attachment and read from it.